# How to better control order of operations in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch file where I am performing a merge function on all PDF files that begin with the letter A that exist in subdirectories;

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /ad/b') do (

START /B sejda-console.bat merge -d "%%i\Holding" -o "%%i\Output\Merged.pdf"
if exist "%%i\Holding\A*.pdf" del "%%i\Holding\A*.pdf"
)
```

Once the merge is completed I would like to delete the values in "Holding" and move on to my next subdir. But I find that the last delete line runs before the merge even though I am using START /B.
Am I missing something here, or doing something wrong?

Comment: MC ND has your solution. The START /B option only causes the started process to share the existing console. It does not cause your script to wait for the command to finish. You would need the /WAIT option. But better to use CALL instead. There is no need for START.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `start /b sejda-console.bat` with `call sejda-console.bat`

This way the caller batch will transfer control to the called and when it finishes, the control will return to the caller.